# How do I run multiple browsers simultaneously in Selenium without using tests? I see some use tests, but that's not what I want

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

How do I run multiple browsers simultaneously in Selenium without using tests? I see some use tests, but that's not what I want. I want to put each run of a browser inside a method and then run those methods simultaneously, as many as I need. Please help, I'm not getting much like finding an answer.

Comment: Use a command line application. Initialize the web driver objects in `static void Main(string[] args)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the same Selenium libraries you would use in a normal test project, but add them to a non-test project (like a console app).

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish by running multiple browsers, I can only give the example below of just creating multiple web browers and having each one navigate to a provided url:

```
    var urls = new string[] {"https://google.com/", "https://www.wikipedia.org/", "https://stackoverflow.com"};
    
    // A list for storing each ChromeDriver instance or whatever driver you use (Firefox, Edge, Chrome)
    var chromeDrivers = new List<ChromeDriver>();
    
    // Add three separate browser sessions to your list (or however many you need)
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        chromeDrivers.Add(new ChromeDriver());
    }
    
    // Navigate to a unique URL for each browser session
    for(int i = 0; i < chromeDrivers.Count(); i++)
    {       
        chromeDrivers[i].Navigate().GoToUrl(urls[i]);
    }
    
    // End the webdriver sessions (close and dispose)
    for(int i = 0; i < chromeDrivers.Count(); i++)
    {
        chromeDrivers[i].Quit();
    }
```

The above example should show you three separate browser windows all having navigated to different urls:

[image]